# Databinding during Navigation in UWP

Tags: mvvm, uwp, windows-template-studio

I'm using Windows Template Studio to create a simple UWP app. I'm using the built-in MVVM template for Multiple Pages. 
I have 2 Pages on the app. Both the pages contain the few textboxes where the user can enter some values. Data binding is working perfectly on both the pages individually. My problem is:
When I navigate to Page 2 and return back on Page 1, the value in the Textboxes return to the original initialization values and do not remain the last updated values.

I am expecting that when I return to Page 1 from Page 2, the values on Page 1 should be the last updated values.
I've followed a lot of tutorials but could not find a comprehensive solution to it. 
I am just getting started with UWP and MVVM so it may be hard for me to wrap my head around some of the basic concepts.
Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to think about saving these TextBox values in the [ApplicationData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata). For example, the [ApplicationData.LocalSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings).

When you navigate from page1 to page2, you could save the value in localSettings.

```
var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
localSettings.Values["exampleSetting"] = "Hello Windows";
```

When you get back from page2 to page1. You could get the value from LocalSettings.

```
Object value = localSettings.Values["exampleSetting"];
```

Please see the [Application data sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/ApplicationData) for more details.

Comment: That would be convenient for storing a few values. Going forward I will have a large number of textboxes. Is there any other way to do this

Comment: @gaurav1891 No matter how many text boxes you have, you still need to store the values yourself.

Comment: @Xie, since I need the values to be available only till the app is active, I created a Class which is initialized  from the Shell Page. I am using this Class to retrieve the values every time my page is initialized.

Comment: @gaurav1891 You could create a common class to get the specific value from the LocalSettings.

Comment: @Xavier_Xie, Thank you for your advice. It is working now

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at NavigationCacheMode

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.navigationcachemode

This should allow you to Cache the data you've entered and will persist whilst navigating to different frames